# Why does Chrome render newly declared web fonts in italic by default?

Tags: css, webfonts

It's not the answer to the question above but I've put work I've done on this below as a bit of back ground so's not to rub people up the wrong way!

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the answer, why not leave the question intact for others to see, and [post your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519)? This way, you can help others who may have the same problem down the road...

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out how to stop Chrome rendering newly declared web fonts in italic by default. I'm sure it's something to do with declaring a new web font on block level elements and having various options on your font. You need to reset your font not with font-style:normal; but font-weight:num; as dictated in your font settings (if using Google Fonts). Why it overrides the font style in the first place, I'm all ears!